# Where is the register position in a CPU (real image illustration)?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

I hear that `register` is in CPU, but the CPU iamge I generally see doesn't mark the position of `register`, can anyone provide a real image of CPU with mark of `register` (for example 32 registers in MIPS)?

[CPU image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2HHH.png) , but not marking `register` position.

Another site with [3D CPU Model](https://sketchfab.com/tags/cpu) also without `register` position.

Comment: Registers are so tiny, you won't spot them in a photo.

Comment: You'll have more luck on an older, simpler processor, like say a Z80: http://www.righto.com/2014/10/how-z80s-registers-are-implemented-down.html

Comment: There are some newer examples [here](http://www.chip-architect.com/news/2003_04_20_Looking_at_Intels_Prescott_part2.html) (pentium 4). The physical register files are much larger than what the ISA makes it look like.